# Access C++/CLI Overloaded [] Operator in C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI class:

```
public ref class Foobar
{
    public:
        // methods here etc..

        // operator overload
        double operator[](int index);
}
```

How do I access `Foobar` from C# given that I've tried:

```
Foobar foo = new Foobar();
int i = foo[1];
```

and I get `CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Foobar'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`operator[]` gets special treatment in C++/CLI (and all .NET languages) – rather than being defined as an operator, it's defined as a property named `default`, known as [the default index property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f1ec0b1.aspx).

```c
public ref class Foobar
{
public:
    // methods here etc..

    property double default[int];
}
```

Comment: You're talking about the *default indexer*. which is a special case of *indexed properties*.